# How to List all Child pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a parent page A with with child pages X, Y, Z, D

I want to display link to all child pages on page X and Y

When you go to page X and Y, you should see a list of all child pages X, Y, Z, D

For some reason I get only the child page (page D)

I am using this function.

```
$args = array(
'sort_order' => 'asc',
'sort_column' => 'post_title',
//'hierarchical' => 1,
'exclude' => '',
'include' => '',
'meta_key' => '',
'meta_value' => '',
'authors' => '',
'child_of' => A,
'parent' => -1,
'exclude_tree' => '',
'number' => '',
'offset' => 0,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 

if ( $pages) 
{   



    foreach($pages as $page)

{
$page = '<ul> <li> <a href=" ' .  get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '"> ' .$page->post_title . ' </a> </li></ul>';
}
return $page;








}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about something simpler: `$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => A, 'sort_column' => 'post_title', 'sort_order' => 'asc' ) );`

Answer (score 0):

In the example, you are failing to close your if statement. Also you can use echo with your foreach instead of return. I cleaned up your code a little bit.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'child_of' => '1',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $pages = get_pages($args);

    if ($pages) {
        foreach ($pages as $page) :
            echo ' <li><a href="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '"> ' . $page->post_title . ' </a></li>';
        endforeach;
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @Geoffrey I used foreach :   endforeach; instead of foreach  () {  } and it worked. The thing is I dont want to echo right away, I just want to return the value and call the function later, something like wpb_list_child_pages() to display all the links. When I use echo $page;  it works, when I use return $page;  it display one link only

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and it worked

I modified my foreach

```
$links = '';    
foreach($pages as $page) {

$links .= '<ul> <li> <a href=" ' .  get_page_link( $page->ID ) .     '"> '     .$page->post_title . ' </a> </li></ul>';

}
return $links;
```

Before  I used
     $links = instead of $links .=